# User accounts and family settings

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2013

I'm trying to add an email account into Outlook and the instructions from GoDaddy require me to click on Mail in User Accounts and Family Settings.  When I do that, nothing happens.

Comment: there is not really a question in your question

Answer (score 0):

Here are instructions for setting up the account in [Outlook.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287532)

[GoDaddy](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4715/setting-up-your-email-address-with-pop) & [GoDaddy](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2649/outlook-2007-setting-up-workspace-email?locale=en#Walk%20Through?ci=53570)

1. Start Outlook.
2. On the Tools menu, click to select Email Accounts.
3. In the Email Accounts dialog box, click to select the Add a new
   E-mail Account option, and then click Next.
4. In the Server Type dialog box, click POP3, and then click Next
5. In the E-mail Accounts dialog box, enter the required information by
   using the following guidelines:

**User Information.**

Your Name: This should be your full name.

Email Address: Your ISP provides this information.

Your e-mail address usually takes the form of a combination of your first and last name and the name of your ISP, separated by the at sign (@) and periods. For example, Patricia Doyle uses an ISP by the name of Adatum.net. The ISP may assign an email address of PatriciaD@adatum.net.

**Logon Information**

User Name: This is usually the part of your email address to the left of the at sign (@).

Password: Enter the password that your ISP provided.

You may click to select the check box to have Outlook remember your email account password.

**Server Information**

Incoming Mail Server (POP3): This is the name of the POP3 server that holds your messages before you download it to your computer.

Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP): This is the name of the Outgoing email server. Enter the server names in lower case in both the Incoming email server and the Outgoing email server. The names may be in the form of mail.adatum.net, or they could be in the form of an IP address such as 168.192.10.1.

Click **Test Account Settings**. This is a new capability in Outlook. This feature calls a dialog box that displays, in a step-by-step manner, each phase of testing the configuration that you have just input. The following occurs when you click Test Account Settings:

The connectivity of your system to the Internet is confirmed.
You are logged on to the SMTP server.
You are logged on to the POP3 server.
It is determined if the POP3 server needs to be logged on to first. If necessary, Outlook automatically sets Log on to incoming mail server before sending mail.
A test message is sent. This message explains any changes that Outlook made to your initial setup.

Click **More Settings**. This takes you to the Internet Email Settings dialog box, where you may further modify your Internet e-mail account.